# check 2 arrays if the result is equal in vue

Tags: arrays, vue.js, if-statement

I need help, I have two array like this

```
let A = ['a', 'b', 'c']
let B = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

and I try this but not work

```
if(A === B) {
  console.log('EQUAL')
} else {
  console.log('NOT EQUAL')
}
```

how to check if they are equal in vue? how to implement it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compare arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a function which checks if they are equal by doing the following:

```js
let A = ['a', 'b', 'c']
let B = ['a', 'b', 'c']
let C = ['a', 'b', 'd']
    
function isEqual(arr1, arr2) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    if (arr1[i] !== arr2[i]) return false;
  }
  // return true if above checks are passed
  return true;
}
    
console.log(isEqual(A, B))
console.log(isEqual(A, C))
```

EDIT:
You should add a if check to avoid nullpointerexceptions

```
function isEqual(arr1, arr2) {
   if (arr1.length !== arr2.length) return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An easier way would be using `JSON.stringify`
(ie)

```
if(JSON.stringify(arr1) === JSON.stringify(arr2))
```

Using the above you can compare multidimensional array of `n` level and no `for-loops` are needed